# Invalid entry CRC oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

When trying yo install Oracle 11g i get this error :

> invalid entry CRC (expected 0x17f644b4 but got 0xfbada364)

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

> invalid entry CRC (expected 0x17f644b4 but got 0xfbada364)

I think that this error implies that the installation file contains corrupted packages, that cannot be extracted during installation.

Try troubleshooting the installation by [reviewing the Log File](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32006/ts.htm#i1090449) Or try to obtain another oracle installation.

Comment: @Pointer try troubleshooting the installation. Follow the link i provided in my answer